# JPanel wont appear until being resized

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel

im Learning to make Java apps using JFrame , JPanel ,etc
So when compiling it , it always return blank Panel[image]

But after either resizing by pulling the sides or even full screening the apps the Panel appear like this

[image]

How do i adjust so the Panel is shown when the apps start without the need to manually resize the screen?

This is my Display Code

```
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(600,400);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        loadWeapon();
        loadMaterial();
```

Thanks in advance!
Cheers.

Comment: And like ALL the other questions that have been asked - call `setVisible` AFTER you have established the UI - otherwise call `revalidate` and `repaint` on the container which has changed

Comment: Just to be sure so i add all the component like button etc to the panel first then set the visibility right? Edit: Oh yeah it works thanks @MadProgrammer

Comment: That's the easiest approach - Swing layouts are lazy, you need to tell them when you want them updated - calling `setVisible` last in this case will cause a layout pass to be triggered automatically